# Nav buttons need to be pressed twice to advance through Array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I created a pair of nav buttons (next and previous) to navigate through an array of images but something stange is happening at the beginning and end of the array. I have to hit the next or previous button twice to move forward or back. Once I do that at the beginning or end of the array everything works normally. Can someone see what's going wrong?

```
    public Texture2D tex;
    public string[] galleryImages;
    public Button nextBtn;
    public Button prevBtn;

    int randomIndex;
    int currentIndex = 0;
    public Color inactiveColor = new Color(0.2F, 0.3F, 0.4F, 0.5F);

    string[] arctopithecusImages;
    string[] arctopithecusPNGImages;
    string[] gulonImages;
    string[] scythianWolfImages;
    string[] simivulpaImages;
    string[] succorathImages;
    string[] tatusImages;

    // System.Random rand = new System.Random();

    // Create a master Array of all image files located in all Image locations
    void Start()
    {
        // Build Gallery Arrays
        arctopithecusImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.jpg");
        arctopithecusPNGImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.png");
        gulonImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/GULON/", "*.jpg");
        scythianWolfImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/SCYTHIAN-WOLF/", "*.png");
        simivulpaImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/SIMIVULPA/", "*.png");
        succorathImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/SUCCORATH/", "*.png");
        tatusImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/TATUS/", "*.png");
        // Concatenate all Folder Array into single Array
        galleryImages = 
            arctopithecusImages.Concat(arctopithecusPNGImages)
                .Concat(gulonImages)
                .Concat(scythianWolfImages)
                .Concat(simivulpaImages)
                .Concat(succorathImages)
                .Concat(tatusImages)
                .ToArray();

        Debug.Log(galleryImages.Length);
    }

    IEnumerator loader(int indexNum)
    {
        WWW www = new WWW("file://" + galleryImages[indexNum]);         // get the first file from disk

        yield return www;                                               // Wait unill its loaded
        tex = new Texture2D(512,512);                                   // create a new Texture2D
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);                                  // put the image file into the new Texture2D

        Rect rct = new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height);
        Vector2 pvt = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);

        GameObject screenShotImg = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GalleryImgHolder");
        Image img = screenShotImg.GetComponent<Image>();
        img.sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, rct, pvt);
    }

    public void LoadImg()
    {
        if(tex == null)
        {
            StartCoroutine("loader", currentIndex);
            Debug.Log(currentIndex);
        } else {
            currentIndex = Random.Range(0,galleryImages.Length);
            StartCoroutine("loader", currentIndex);
            Debug.Log(currentIndex);
        }
    }

    public void nextImage()
    {
        Debug.Log(currentIndex);

        // Increment through gallery
        if(currentIndex != galleryImages.Length - 1)
        {
            StartCoroutine("loader", currentIndex++);
            prevBtn.enabled = true;
            prevBtn.interactable = true;
            nextBtn.enabled = true;
            nextBtn.interactable = true;
            // nextBtn.image.color = new Color(255f,255f,255f,1f);
        } else if (currentIndex == galleryImages.Length - 1){
            nextBtn.enabled = false;
            nextBtn.interactable = false;
            // nextBtn.image.color = new Color(255f,255f,255f,.5f);
        }
    }

    public void prevImage()
    {
        Debug.Log(currentIndex);

        // Decrement through gallery
        if(currentIndex != 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine("loader", currentIndex--);
            nextBtn.enabled = true;
            nextBtn.interactable = true;

            prevBtn.enabled = true;
            prevBtn.interactable = true;
            // prevBtn.image.color = new Color(255f,255f,255f,1f);
        } else if (currentIndex == 0){
            prevBtn.enabled = false;
            prevBtn.interactable = false;
            // prevBtn.image.color = new Color(255f,255f,255f,.5f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is code for `nextBtn` Click and `precBtn` Click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your yield return is the problem, that's not how its supposed to be used, if you want to wait for asynchronous methods to finish, learn how to use async/await.